# Is there a way to create a .jar completely on the phone?

Tags: java, android, mobile, jar

I am fairly new to Java and almost entirely new to writing Java on my phone. My laptop is broken and the replacement seems far off, so I'm trying to set up my phone as a complete replacement in the meantime.

Question:
I have termux with emacs for writing and CLDC for running jar files but I haven't found out how to convert my .java/.class files without Java's jar command. Is there a way to create a Java Archive while only using an Android phone?

Comment: refer this [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Get-Java-on-Android)

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing a [GNURoot](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=gnuroot&c=apps). Rooting your device is not required. Once installed, you will have access to a command line interface.

From there, you should be able to use `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` to install `jar`, and you may be able to use it to compile your source files.

Good luck!